# How to pass JSON `null` value to `nil` value in swift?

Tags: ios, json, swift, alamofire

I have this `json` wherein `hospitalNumber` has value and there is instances that it returns `null` value. The `hospitalNumber` has significance since its a part of the parameter needed for the endpoint in API. Please see sample `json`:

```
{
  "responseMessage": "Request successful",
  "data": [
    {
      "hospitalNumber": null,
      "patientName": "Manual Entry",
      "totalAmount": 10339.8000,
      "manualEntry": true
    },
    {
     "hospitalNumber": "1111111",
     "patientName": "test patient",
     "totalAmount": 932.5000,
    "manualEntry": false
   }
 ]
}
```

And below is my APIService for the endpoint that will pull the `json` above.

```
typealias getPatientDetailsPerPayoutTaskCompletion = (_ patientDetailsPerPayout: [PatientPayoutDetails]?, _ error: NetworkError?) -> Void

 //Patient procedure details per patient
 //parameterName is .searchByHospitalNumber = "hospitalNumber"
    static func getPatientDetailsPerPayout(periodId: Int, doctorNumber: String, parameterName: PatientParameter, hospitalNumber: String, manualEntry: Bool, completion: @escaping getPatientDetailsPerPayoutTaskCompletion) {


        guard let patientDetailsPerPayoutURL = URL(string: "\(Endpoint.Patient.patientProcedureDetails)?periodId=\(periodId)&doctorNumber=\(doctorNumber)\(parameterName.rawValue)\(hospitalNumber)&manualEntry=\(manualEntry)") else {

            completion(nil, .invalidURL)
            return
        }

        let sessionManager = Alamofire.SessionManager.default
        sessionManager.session.getAllTasks { (tasks) in
            tasks.forEach({ $0.cancel() })
        }

        Alamofire.request(patientDetailsPerPayoutURL, method: .get, encoding: JSONEncoding.default).responseJSON { (response) in
            print(patientDetailsPerPayoutURL)
            guard HelperMethods.reachability(responseResult: response.result) else {
                completion(nil, .noNetwork)
                return
            }

            guard let statusCode = response.response?.statusCode else {
                completion(nil, .noStatusCode)
                return
            }

            switch(statusCode) {
            case 200:
                guard let jsonData = response.data else {
                    completion(nil, .invalidJSON)
                    return
                }

                let decoder = JSONDecoder()

                do {
                    let patientDetailsPayout = try decoder.decode(RootPatientPayoutDetails.self, from: jsonData)
                    if (patientDetailsPayout.data?.isEmpty)! {
                        completion(nil, .noRecordFound)
                    } else {
                    completion(patientDetailsPayout.data, nil)
                    }
                } catch {
                    completion(nil, .invalidJSON)
                }

            case 400: completion(nil, .badRequest)
            case 404: completion(nil, .noRecordFound)
            default:
                print("**UNCAPTURED STATUS CODE FROM (getPatientDetailsPayout)\nSTATUS CODE: \(statusCode)")
                completion(nil, .uncapturedStatusCode)
            }
        }
    }
```

**getPatientPayoutDetails Function**

```
 func getPerPatientPayoutDetails(from: String, manualEntry: Bool) {
    //SVProgressHUD.setDefaultMaskType(.black)
    //SVProgressHUD.setForegroundColor(.white)
    SVProgressHUD.setBackgroundColor(.lightGray)
    SVProgressHUD.show(withStatus: "Retrieving Patient Procedures")

    APIService.PatientList.getPatientDetailsPerPayout(periodId: doctorPayoutWeek[3].periodId!, doctorNumber: doctorNumber, parameterName: .selectedByHospitalNumber, hospitalNumber: from, manualEntry: manualEntry) { (patientPayout, error) in

        guard let patientPerPayoutDetails = patientPayout, error == nil else {
            if let networkError = error {
                switch networkError {
                case .noRecordFound:
                    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "No Record Found", message: "You don't have current payment remittance", preferredStyle: .alert)
                    alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default))
                case .noNetwork:
                    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "No Network", message: "\(networkError.rawValue)", preferredStyle: .alert)
                    alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default))
                    self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
                default:
                    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: "There is something went wrong. Please try again", preferredStyle: .alert)
                    alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default))
                    self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
                }
            }

            SVProgressHUD.dismiss()
            return
        }
        self.selectedPatientPayment = patientPerPayoutDetails
        print(self.selectedPatientPayment)
        SVProgressHUD.dismiss()
        return
    }
}
```

**tableView**

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    switch indexPath.section {
    case 0: break
    case 1: break
    case 2:

        filteredPatient = indexPath.row
        let selectedpatient = patientList[filteredPatient].hospitalNumber
        let selectedEntry = patientList[filteredPatient].manualEntry
        self.isBrowseAll = false
        getPerPatientPayoutDetails(from: selectedpatient!, manualEntry: selectedEntry)
    default: break
    }
}
```

The endpoint which requires `null` string in `hospitalNumber` when it is nil

```
https://sample.com/openapi/getpatientpayoutdetails?periodId=579&doctorNumber=2866&hospitalNumber=null&manualEntry=true
```

As you can see hospital number has an important role for the endpoint. My problem is, once the `tableView` has reloaded it shows the data properly but when I `didSelect` the `cell` with `null` hospitalNumber, my app crashes and show **Found nil error** since `hospitalNumber` has `null` value. Hope you understand what I am trying to explain, please help me. Thank you

Comment: If you are not sure that you will get a definite value for a key or not, make that variable as `optional` in your `Codable` model. And `don't force unwrap`, use `guard-let/if-let`.

Comment: @SharadChauhan I have this `struct Patient: Codable { var hospitalNumber: String? var patientName: String? var totalAmount: Double var manualEntry: Bool
   enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
      case hospitalNumber = “hospitalNumber”
       case patientName = “patientName”
       case totalAmount = “totalAmount”
       case manualEntry = “manualEntry”
   }
}

Comment: What is the expected behavior if hospitalNumber is `nil`? By the way the `switch` in `didSelect` is overkill. Just check `if indexPath.section == 2 { filteredPatient = indexPath.row ... }`

Comment: @vadian if `hospitalNumber` is `nil`. it should return `null` value. Because the endpoint should be like this `https://sample.com/openapi/getpatientpayoutdetails?periodId=579&doctorNumber=2866&hospitalNumber=null&manualEntry=true`

Answer (score 0):

Your `Codable` model is correct, all you need is `guard-let/if-let` to prevent crash:

```
if let selectedpatient = patientList[filteredPatient].hospitalNumber, let selectedEntry = patientList[filteredPatient].manualEntry {
   self.isBrowseAll = false
   getPerPatientPayoutDetails(from: selectedpatient, manualEntry: selectedEntry)
}
```

**Updated:**
If you want to create `endPoint` in case of nil also then use `coalescing operator` :

```
getPerPatientPayoutDetails(from: selectedpatient ?? "null", manualEntry: selectedEntry)
```

Comment: I tried your answer, my app didn't crashed but when I print the value of `manualEntryFlag` why does the value changed from `true` to `false`. Which is I should get the actual value of the parameter

Comment: There is no code to change the value of `manualEntryFlag`, so you might wanna check the value again and properly.

Answer (score 0):

In didSelect do like

```
let selectedpatient:String!  //or Int whatever type it is right not this line initializes selected patient with nil 
//below line will check for nil and ALSO NULL if NULL or nil it will not reassigne selectedpatient which means  selectedpatient will remain nil 
 if let hsptlNbr =  patientList[filteredPatient].hospitalNumber as? yourDataType{
    selectedpatient =  hsptlNbr
}
```

after this you can pass this as nil or value if exist in below method

```
getPerPatientPayoutDetails(from: selectedpatient, manualEntry: selectedEntry)
```

Change `func getPerPatientPayoutDetails(from: String, manualEntry: Bool)`

to

```
func getPerPatientPayoutDetails(from: String?, manualEntry: Bool)
```

Comment: Did you mean `String?`? Because it's the other way around. This code will crash if you don't set it with a value.

Comment: it will not crash if  @titus  set getPerPatientPayoutDetails(from: String?
from as optional :)

Comment: Or yes he can use as let selectedpatient:String?

Comment: It will crash. When you implicitly unwrap a value with `!`. You are telling the compiler it is not `nil`. So when you try to read it, if it's `nil` it will crash.